# How add Onpressed function to each value of the list

Tags: flutter

I was haven difficulties navigating an item in a list to new .dart file, here is my mainpage i imported the second file

```
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => new _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {

  final List<String>listof=["Decimal Numbers","Binary Numbers","Decimal-to-Binary Conversion","Binary Arithmetic","Complements of Binary Numbers","Signed Numbers","Arithmetic Operations with Signed Numbers","Hexadecimal Numbers","Octal Numbers","Binary Coded Decimal (BCD)"];



    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Scaffold(
           appBar: new AppBar(
             title: new Text(
               "Computer System Theory",
               style:  new TextStyle(fontSize: 19.0),
             ), 
             backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,

          actions: <Widget>[
            new IconButton(
              icon: new Icon(Icons.search),
              onPressed: ()=>debugPrint("Search"),
             ),
          ],

       ),
       body: new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(

         itemBuilder: (_, int index)=>listDataItem(this.listof[index],),
         itemCount: this.listof.length,


       ),
       ),       
    );
  }
}

    class listDataItem extends StatelessWidget{

      String itemName;
      listDataItem(this.itemName);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return new Card(

          elevation: 7.0,

          child: new Container(

            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),

            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget> [

                new CircleAvatar(
                  child: new Text(itemName[0]),

                  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,

                ),
                new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
                new Text(itemName,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),

              ],
            ),
        ),); 
      }

    }
```

i tried this method but i don't know how to add the onpress function to a iten in a list, if i click on any value on a list should take me to the respectful page e.g binary.dart

here is my binary code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Binary extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BinaryState createState() => _BinaryState();
}

class _BinaryState extends State<Binary> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double cWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8;
    return new Container (
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      width: cWidth,
      child: new Column (
        children: <Widget>[
          new Text ("Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 Long text 1 ", textAlign: TextAlign.left),
          new Text ("Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2, Long Text 2", textAlign: TextAlign.left),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Make use of InkWell or GestureDetector

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your list items with `InkWell` or `GestureDetector`.

Example: In your `listDataItem` class's `build` method, you are returning a `Card`

Wrap it with a InkWell.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    print('inkwell');
  },
  child: Card(...
```

Answer (score 0):

I did illustrate the code here i hope this help

```
class listDataItem extends StatelessWidget{

      final String itemName;
      listDataItem(this.itemName);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context){
        return InkWell(
        onTap: () {
        },
        child : Card(

          elevation: 7.0,

          child: new Container(

            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(6.0),

            child: new Row(
              children: <Widget> [

                new CircleAvatar(
                  child: new Text(itemName[0]),

                  backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,

                ),
                new Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0)),
                new Text(itemName,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0)),

              ],
            ),
        ),),
        ); 
    }

}
```